# Postfix sending limitation

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I am a complete newbie in server-administration, but with this new work I am actually the system admin. So, first of all, I am kinda sorry for my poor property of language - but I am actually a web designer.

Anyhow, I am working on a website; this website has a simple form that actually sends e-mail. The problem is: sometimes the mail is sent and some other times it isn't. After a lot of try-outs I am starting to understand that it is a server problem; at first I thought it was a problem with the code, but the e-mails - sometimes - work just fine so I tried to send several mails in order to understand if a field - of this long form - could be the problem. But nope, i understood it isn't that.

So considering I was informed that the server had a poor server admin (well, maybe worse than me :P ), I thought it could be a problem with postfix.

As you guys know, there might be any limitation? Like a number of e-mails that the server could send every hour - or something like that?

I tried some combinations to understand the time pattern, but for now it looks kinda random to me.

Any suggestion or solution?
And, most of all, how do I change these parameters - if there are - of Postfix that define the limits of e-mails (and such) that the server can send?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Check the mail logs.

Comment: "sometimes the mail is sent and some other times it isn't" are you sure it's *sent* and not *received*? Mails get sometimes thrown into junk/spam mailboxes, instead of people inbox.

Comment: @ringø yeah i meant received; sometimes it is received and sometimes it isn't (and it's not in the spam either).

Comment: @MichaelHampton how do i do that? :)
EDIT: I checked the var/log/mail.log but it is an empty file.